# group_by throws up error messages within larger function

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to apply the following function to a dataframe, of which a sample is found below. I had the function working without using dplyr functions, but wanted to apply group_by to group by year. Since that was not possible, I used the dplyr commands. Now, however, I continue to get all sorts of error messages, depending on how I try to solve the problem. The last one was:

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function".

Since I am not making headway no matter what I do, I would greatly appreciate your support. The problems seem to be associated with the group_by function. I am new at R and this is the first function I am writing, so please be gentle. Thanks a lot.

```
depDistOverParties=function(DF, year, percVote, deps){
  group_by(DF, year) %>%
  mutate(DF, depsIdeal = (percVote / 100) * deps, 
         depsWhole = floor(depsIdeal), 
         depsPart = depsIdeal - depsWhole)
  arrange(DF, desc(depsPart))
  mutate(DF, depsLeft = round(sum(depsPart)), 
         n = nrow(percVote), 
         depsZero = n - depsLeft, 
         addDeps = c(rep(1, depsLeft), rep(0, depsZero)),
         totalLevelDeps = depsWhole + addDeps)
}
```

Here is the execution of the function:

```
df2=depDistOverParties(df, df$year, df$percVotesYear, df$totalSeats350)
```

Here is the sample data:

```
df=structure(list(year = c(2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
                        2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
                        2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
                        2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
                        2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), party = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                       4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
                                                                                       10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 8L, 
                                                                                       14L, 15L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 8L, 14L, 15L), .Label = c("AMAIUR", 
                                                                                                                                                      "BNG", "C", "CC", "CIU", "COMPROMIS", "EHBILDU", "PODEMOS", "EQUO", 
                                                                                                                                                      "ERC", "IU", "PACMA", "PNV", "PP", "PSOE", "UPYD"), class = "factor"), 
               totalVotes = c(212543L, 174629L, 779425L, 298139L, 969946L, 
                              306128L, 10278010L, 11289335L, 306079L, 334498L, 184037L, 
                              143881L, 1015691L, 125306L, 216748L, 256985L, 1686040L, 324317L, 
                              10866566L, 7003511L, 1143225L, 3556267L, 567253L, 601782L, 
                              939204L, 221602L, 302316L, 5247050L, 7310128L, 5590209L, 
                              3141570L, 483488L, 184713L, 632234L, 286702L, 287014L, 5087538L, 
                              7941236L, 5443846L), totalSeats = c(2L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                                  6L, 154L, 169L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 16L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 
                                                                  186L, 110L, 5L, 41L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 70L, 123L, 90L, 
                                                                  32L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 0L, 5L, 71L, 137L, 85L), totalSeats350 = c(350, 
                                                                                                                              350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 
                                                                                                                              350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 
                                                                                                                              350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 
                                                                                                                              350, 350), totalVotesYear = c(24614234L, 24614234L, 24614234L, 
                                                                                                                                                            24614234L, 24614234L, 24614234L, 24614234L, 24614234L, 24614234L, 
                                                                                                                                                            23300805L, 23300805L, 23300805L, 23300805L, 23300805L, 23300805L, 
                                                                                                                                                            23300805L, 23300805L, 23300805L, 23300805L, 23300805L, 23300805L, 
                                                                                                                                                            24335811L, 24335811L, 24335811L, 24335811L, 24335811L, 24335811L, 
                                                                                                                                                            24335811L, 24335811L, 24335811L, 23488341L, 23488341L, 23488341L, 
                                                                                                                                                            23488341L, 23488341L, 23488341L, 23488341L, 23488341L, 23488341L
                                                                                                                              ), percVotesYear = c(0.863496300555199, 0.709463475483332, 
                                                                                                                                                   3.1665620794862, 1.2112463056945, 3.94058982294554, 1.24370313534843, 
                                                                                                                                                   41.7563674742021, 45.8650673427416, 1.24350406354307, 1.43556413608886, 
                                                                                                                                                   0.789831080943341, 0.617493687449854, 4.3590382392368, 0.537775411622045, 
                                                                                                                                                   0.930216788647431, 1.10290180961559, 7.23597317775073, 1.39187036671051, 
                                                                                                                                                   46.6360110734372, 30.0569486762367, 4.90637555226096, 14.6133079353715, 
                                                                                                                                                   2.33093937161166, 2.47282492455255, 3.8593494993859, 0.910600431602629, 
                                                                                                                                                   1.24226803043465, 21.5610237932896, 30.0385633336814, 22.9711226800701, 
                                                                                                                                                   13.3750186954455, 2.0584169822807, 0.78640292219872, 2.69169287009244, 
                                                                                                                                                   1.22061409105053, 1.2219424096406, 21.6598439200112, 33.8092673296935, 
                                                                                                                                                   23.1768007795868), totalSeatsYear = c(349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 348L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         349L, 349L, 349L, 349L, 349L), percSeatsYear = c(0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.571428571428571, 2.85714285714286, 0.857142857142857, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.71428571428571, 44, 48.2857142857143, 0.285714285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          2, 0.571428571428571, 0.571428571428571, 4.57142857142857, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.285714285714286, 0, 0.857142857142857, 3.14285714285714, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.42857142857143, 53.1428571428571, 31.4285714285714, 1.42857142857143, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          11.7142857142857, 2.28571428571429, 2.57142857142857, 0.571428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 1.71428571428571, 20, 35.1428571428571, 25.7142857142857, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          9.14285714285714, 2.28571428571429, 0.571428571428571, 2.57142857142857, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 1.42857142857143, 20.2857142857143, 39.1428571428571, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          24.2857142857143), disprop = c(-0.292067729126628, -0.138034904054761, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -0.309419222343346, -0.354103448551645, -3.36916125151697, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.470582578937282, 2.24363252579788, 2.42064694297269, -0.957789777828785, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.56443586391114, -0.218402509514769, -0.0460651160212828, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.212390332191772, -0.252061125907759, -0.930216788647431, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -0.245758952472733, -4.09311603489358, 0.0367010618609223, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         6.50684606941999, 1.37162275233471, -3.47780412368953, -2.89902222108574, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -0.0452250858973695, 0.0986036468760259, -3.28792092795733, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -0.910600431602629, 0.47201768385106, -1.56102379328965, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         5.10429380917576, 2.74316303421559, -4.2321615525884, 0.227297303433587, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -0.214974350770148, -0.120264298663872, -1.22061409105053, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.206629018930833, -1.37412963429692, 5.33358981316365, 1.10891350612751
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -39L))
```

Comment: There are too many problems with your code. First, don't give the first argument when using the %>% operator.Second, actually use the pipe operator. Third, after a `group_by`, it is best to use a summarize as it will give a single row for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
depDistOverParties=function(DF, year, percVote, deps){
        year <- enquo(year)
        percVote <- enquo(percVote)
        deps <- enquo(deps)
    #browser()
        DF %>%  group_by(!! year) %>%
                mutate(depsIdeal = (!! percVote / 100) * !! deps, 
                       depsWhole = floor(depsIdeal), 
                       depsPart = depsIdeal - depsWhole) %>% 
                arrange(desc(depsPart))

 #This part throws an error but I don't know why
 #mutate(depsLeft = round(sum(depsPart)), 
 #    n = nrow(!! percVote), 
 #    depsZero = n - depsLeft, 
 #    addDeps = c(rep(1, depsLeft), rep(0, depsZero)),
 #    totalLevelDeps = depsWhole + addDeps)
}

depDistOverParties(df, year, percVotesYear, totalSeats350)
```

To programming using `dplyr` check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)